# Actionscript 3.0 Embed Font - Text Not Appearing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am creating dynamic TextFields in actionscript 3.0.  Like many others, my text disappears when I set `.embedFonts = true;`

ArialSlim is embedded and exported for actionscript.  I have successfully tested with `trace(Font.enumerateFonts());`

Interestingly enough, when I comment out the embed line (as shown below), the font works properly.

Alternatively, `.setTextFormat();` also works properly without the `.embedFonts` line.

So my questions is, why?  Will I run into any issues in this case?

```
var divArray = new Array();
var x_Lbl_Array:Array = new Array();

var entries:int = 10;

var labelFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var arial:Font = new ArialSlim();    

labelFormat.font = arial.fontName;
labelFormat.size = 10;

var xVar:int = 0;

for(var loop:int = 0; loop < entries; loop++){
    x_Lbl_Array[loop] = new TextField();

    //x_Lbl_Array[loop].embedFonts = true;
    x_Lbl_Array[loop].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;
    x_Lbl_Array[loop].defaultTextFormat = labelFormat;

    x_Lbl_Array[loop].x = xVar;
    x_Lbl_Array[loop].y = 165;
    x_Lbl_Array[loop].text = "test";

    mc.addChild(x_Lbl_Array[loop]);
    xVar++;
}
```

**Edit:**
I just ran this code from frame 1 with `.embedFonts = true;` and it worked...

Maybe I should mention that I'm having trouble running this code in a method inside an instantiated actionscript class.  The class is located in an external .as file.  Does this help answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I at some point clicked "TLF (DF4)" in the outline format options for my embedded font.  When I corrected this, and chose "Classic (DF3)," it fixed my problem.

I guess what I find to be really weird is that the font was showing properly without `.embedFonts` being set to `true`

Thank you, Daniel.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer (or Daniel's, below) as 'accepted' so that others will notice that your problem has been solved and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: Yes, I had intended to mark my answer, but it wouldn't let me do it right away.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it worked for me (with the embedded font)

check if you have all the characters included.
You can either set the character range, or create a textfield that has all the characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Included characters shouldn't be a problem... I'm including Upper, Lower case and special symbols.  I don't need any more than that.

Comment: [This is a link to my source](http://www.peculiar-motion.com/FlashExamples/textExample.zip)...  Please consult the edit to my post above - this error only occurs when you are instantiating a class that calls this code.

Comment: I don't have CS5.5 or the arial slim font, so I created a new flash file and it worked. Check if you're calling the `populate()` function?